# Can't load texture uniform with glUniform1i function

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, glsl, shader

I try to follow the tutorial on YT on 'The Cherno' channel about OpenGL (you can find my code [here](https://github.com/tmkrudnicki/BasicOpenGL.git)). I have two uniforms `u_Color` and `u_Texture` that I load using `glUniform1i` function called from *Shader.cpp* file. For `u_Color` everything's alright but when I try to load `u_Texture` I obtain error code

> 0x502 (GL_INVALID_OPERATION; Qt debugging stops printing out "Illegal operation" error).

I tried to remove unused calls to "u_Color" uniform in shader AND cpp code, I've tried to use the function outside of GLCall macro and some other stuff but it simply doesn't want to work. I am sure location of the texture is alright (unsigned int) and I think my code looks exactly the same as the one from tutorial that actually works!

I work on Linux system (18.04), with Intel graphic card, and I'm using Qt Creator (Qt Creator 4.11.2 based on Qt 5.14.2) with g++ compiler (7.5.0).

If somebody could check it out I'd really appreciate it.

That's the problematic part of the code from "Shader.cpp"

```
GLuint uniformlocation = static_cast<GLuint>(glGetUniformLocation(m_rendererID, "u_Texture"));
glUniform1f(uniformLocation, value);
```

And here's fragment shader that uses u_Texture

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;

in vec2 v_TexCoord;

uniform vec4 u_Color;
uniform sampler2D u_Texture;

void main()
{
    vec4 texColor = texture2D(u_Texture, v_TexCoord);
    color = texColor;
}
```

Comment: You have to past the relevant code in the question!

Comment: Is `u_Texture` an active program resource? That means, is  `u_Texture` "used" in the shader code?

Comment: Yes, it is an active resource; I will upload some code in a moment if this github link isn't enough

Comment: it's public now, sorry about; also I had a problem with figuring out how big sample of code is necessary here to consider it 'minimal, reproducible example'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`glUniform1f`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glUniform.xhtml) sets a value of a uniform of the currently installed program, thus the program has to be installed by [`glUseProgram`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glUseProgram.xhtml), before:

```cpp
GLuint uniformlocation = static_cast<GLuint>(glGetUniformLocation(m_rendererID, "u_Texture"));
glUseProgram(m_rendererID);
glUniform1f(uniformLocation, value);
```

respectively:

```cpp
shader.bind();
shader.setUniform1i("u_Texture", 0);
```

The `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` is caused, by the fact, that there is no current program object.

---

Alternatively you can use [`glProgramUniform`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glProgramUniform.xhtml) to specify the value of a uniform variable for a specified program object

Comment: Thx, it works and I'll check glProgramUniform function as well